# Force quit closed application

Tags: macos, force-quit

I force quit Google Chrome by right-clicking the app icon in the Dock and selecting Force Quit. That seemed to quit Chrome (absence of indicator under app icon). However, when I try opening Google Chrome, nothing happens. When I open the Force Quit window by using the keyboard shortcut,<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd>, Google Chrome is present in the list.

At the same time, Google Chrome does not show up in `ps` output or in Activity Monitor app.

I think that Chrome is actually closed but that macOS thinks it's open. How do I convince macOS that Chrome is, indeed, closed?

I have just installed macOS Mojave.

Comment: Is that really force quit? I use cmnd+opt+esc to get to force quit.

Comment: It's possible that Chrome launches lots of processes, not all of which are killed by Force Quit. You may need to look for other names in Activity Monitor.
Why do you need to Force Quit Chrome? If you have to do that regularly, then I'd say that's your bigger problem.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, the Force Quit dialog came up.

Comment: @benwiggy It’s possible that one of Chrome’s other processes was remaining. I wound up just rebooting so I can’t confirm. This was a one-time thing, Chrome just hung.

Comment: Did you try force quit the app via terminal ? kill <PID number of app>

Comment: @EddGrowl I tried but `ps|grep Chrome` didn’t turn up anything.

Comment: I had this problem again with Launchbar refusing to reopen. When I try to reopen it, I get the error "You can't open the application "LaunchBar.app" because it is not responding." It doesn't show up in ps or force quit.

Answer (score 1):

From searching online, I think I may have run into an edge case. My best guess is that, having just installed Mojave, one of the many new permissions dialogs was generated but hidden behind another window. As I closed programs, some permissions dialogs appeared, including for Chrome. This doesn’t make much sense as a cause but it was related to a major system change so it’s my best guess.

I wound up resolving the issue by rebooting.

Edit: I had the problem again a few more times. Today, FlowVPN wouldn't force quit. I had to hard reboot because macOS was waiting for FlowVPN to close and it wouldn't.